# $("/usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.memsize") No such file or directory

Tags: linux, macos, shell

macOS High Sierra, 10.13.3 (17D102)

- If I run in terminal `sysctl -n hw.memsize` it works fine, I get a number
- If i run `which sysctl` i get `/usr/sbin/sysctl` which seems correct

**How to run the same command from shell script?**
Looking for cross-OS solution. Using pure sh everywhere.

I have tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
$("sysctl -n hw.memsize")
exit 1
```

**1 Result**: line 2: sysctl -n hw.memsize: command not found

```
#!/bin/sh
$("/usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.memsize")
exit 1
```

**2 Result**: line 2: /usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.memsize: No such file or directory

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `sysctl -n hw.memsize`
exit 1
```

**3 Result**: line 2: 17179869184: command not found

Not sure why command not found afte the correct output.

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "sysctl -n hw.memsize"
exit 1
```

**4 Result**: same as running in terminal: *17179869184* But i want to avoid eval.

While 4th works as epxected, it uses eval and i try to avoid it. 3rd seems almost correct and not sure why 2nd says no such file while it does exist.

sh script file has a+x chmod.

Comment: Don't use quotes inside `$(...)`.  It's treating the entire quoted string as the name of the command to run, because, well, that's what quotes mean to do.  Here you don't even need the `$(...)` though, that's if you want to run a command in a subshell and get its stdout back as a string

Answer (score 4):

Literally the same command inside a script should be *exactly the same*:

```
sysctl -n hw.memsize
```

Your tries concentrate more on `$(…)` syntax and I don't know *why* the need for `$(…)` in the first place. If you need it (e.g. let's store the result in a variable), then it should be like

```
memsize=$(sysctl -n hw.memsize)
```

without quotes inside the `$(…)`.

---

> ```
> $("sysctl -n hw.memsize")
> ```
>
> 1 Result: `line 2: sysctl -n hw.memsize: command not found`

It is because of quoting. Your shell treats the entire string as a single word, a single command (executable) to run; while your intention is to pass a command and two arguments. Without quotes you would get `command not found` anyway because the shell would try to evaluate (run in this case) *the result* of the inner command (this is what `$(…)` does), e.g. the result could be `17179869184`. There's no `17179869184` command in your system, is there? Note this `command not found` would come from a different level than when you use quotes.

> ```
> $("/usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.memsize")
> ```
>
> 2 Result: `line 2: /usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.memsize: No such file or directory`

Basically the same as above. Error message is different because of `/` in the "command" but the mechanism is the same.

> ```
> echo `sysctl -n hw.memsize`
> ```
>
> 3 Result: `line 2: 17179869184: command not found`

This *should* work (it's [awful code](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690) though). Are you sure it was not just `` `sysctl -n hw.memsize` `` without `echo`? This would be the same as "without quotes" case explained under your 1st result.